# Trend graph with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following lists:

```
input = ['"25', '"500', '"10000', '"200000', '"1000000']
inComp = ['0.000001', '0.0110633', '4.1396405', '2569.270532', '49085.86398']
quickrComp=['0.0000001', '0.0003665', '0.005637', '0.1209121', '0.807273']
quickComp = ['0.000001', '0.0010253', '0.0318653', '0.8851902', '5.554448']
mergeComp = ['0.000224', '0.004089', '0.079448', '1.973014', '13.034443']
```

I need to create a trend graph to demonstrate the growth of the values of inComp, quickrComp, quickComp, mergeComp as the input values grow (input is the x-axis). I am using matplotlib.pyplot, and the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(input,quickrComp, label="QR")
ax.plot(input,mergeComp, label="merge")
ax.plot(input, quickComp, label="Quick")
ax.plot(input, inComp, label="Insrção")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

However, what is happening is this: the values of the y-axis are disordered; the values of quickrComp on the y-axis are first inserted; then all mergeComp values and so on. I need the y-axis values to start at 0 and end at the highest of the 4-row values. How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but mind that you are plotting strings, which are unordered (as in, matplotlib cannot know if you want `"second pirate"` or `"fourth viking"` to appear first on the axis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: First, your y-values are strings. You need to convert the data to numeric (`float`) type. Second, your y-values in one of the lists are huge as compared to the remaining three lists. So you will have to convert the y-scale to logarithmic to see the trend. You can, in principle, convert your x-values to float (integers) as well but in your example, you don't need it. In case you want to do that, you will also have to remove the `"` from the front of each x-value.

A word of caution: Don't name your variables the same as in-built functions. In your case, you should rename `input` to something else, `input1` for instance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

input1 = ['"25', '"500', '"10000', '"200000', '"1000000']
inComp = ['0.000001', '0.0110633', '4.1396405', '2569.270532', '49085.86398']
quickrComp=['0.0000001', '0.0003665', '0.005637', '0.1209121', '0.807273']
quickComp = ['0.000001', '0.0010253', '0.0318653', '0.8851902', '5.554448']
mergeComp = ['0.000224', '0.004089', '0.079448', '1.973014', '13.034443']


ax.plot(input1, list(map(float, quickrComp)), label="QR")
ax.plot(input1, list(map(float, mergeComp)), label="merge")
ax.plot(input1, list(map(float, quickComp)), label="Quick")
ax.plot(input1, list(map(float, inComp)), label="Insrção")
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: On the variables with the name of functions, an original was in english and I did not pay attention at the time of translating. Thank you!